# What is the C++/CLI equivalent to a VB6 Collection?

Tags: collections, vb6, c++-cli, equivalent

I already tried ArrayList^ and VB6 gives me a 'Type mismatch' error. I don't see a C++/CLI 'Collection' or 'List'.

So what is the equivalent, if there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, doesn't work, VB6 wants its own Collection class.  I'm fairly shocked how that turned out.  I thought, easy peasy, just add a reference to c:\windows\system32\msvbvm60.dll and use the interop library that generates.  Then:

```
VBA::Collection^ coll = gcnew VBA::Collection();
```

Kaboom:

```
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A4C4671C-499F-101B-BB78-00AA00383CBB} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
```

Class not registered.  Looked in the registry, it's there under HKLM\CLSID but the InprocServer32 key is blank.  *Blank*.  That's not good.  Changed it to point to point to msvbvm60.dll.  Kaboom, 0x80040111, "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class".

This isn't going to fly.  Abandon all hope the way I see it, unless you can refactor the VB6 code.

Comment: Or he can make a custom `VBA.Collection` factory in VB6 -- a multi-use class with a single method `NewCollection` that returns `New Collection`

Comment: I wound up abandoning all hope. :) Found another way. Thanks for the help.